# Kendo ui Grid mvc with sql database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, view, kendo-grid

I'm trying to make a grid view for a driver table I have in SQL Server.

Here are my classes:

`Driver.cs`:

```
public partial class Driver
{
        public Driver()
        {
            this.CarsToDrivers = new HashSet<CarsToDriver>();
        }

        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string FamilyName { get; set; }
        public string Licence { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> ExperienceYears { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CarsToDriver> CarsToDrivers { get; set; }
}
```

`CarsToDriver.cs`:

```
 public partial class CarsToDriver
 {
        public CarsToDriver()
        {
            this.Role_TimeRestriction = new HashSet<Role_TimeRestriction>();
        }

        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
        public System.Guid CarId { get; set; }
        public System.Guid DriverId { get; set; }
        public string KilometersDriven { get; set; }

        public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
        public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
        public virtual Role_DayRestriction Role_DayRestriction { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Role_TimeRestriction> Role_TimeRestriction { get; set; }
 }
```

Because of the circular reference I created a viewModel class:

`DriverViewModel.cs`:

```
 public class DriverViewModel
 {
      public DriverViewModel()
      {
                this.CarsToDrivers = new HashSet<CarsToDriverViewModel>();
      }

      public Guid  Id { get; set; }
      public String Name { get; set; }
      public String FamilyName { get; set; }
      public String Licence { get; set; }
      public short? ExperienceYears { get; set; }
      public int UserId { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<CarsToDriverViewModel> CarsToDrivers { get; set; }
}
```

I created a controller:

`DriverController.cs`:

```
public class DriverController : Controller
{
        private CarManagerDbEntities db = new CarManagerDbEntities();

        // GET: Driver
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult Get([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var drivers = db.Drivers.Select(d => new DriverViewModel()
            {
                ExperienceYears = d.ExperienceYears,
                Id = d.Id,
                UserId = d.UserId,
                Name = d.Name,
                FamilyName = d.FamilyName,
                Licence = d.Licence
            });

            return this.Json(drivers.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
}
```

`Index.cshtml`:

```
@using CarManagerWebApplication.Models

    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<DriverViewModel>()
              .Name("Driver")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(o => o.Name);
          columns.Bound(o => o.FamilyName);
          columns.Bound(o => o.Licence);
          columns.Bound(o => o.ExperienceYears);
      })
      .DataSource( d => d
                .Ajax()
                .Read(r => r.Action("Get", "Driver")) )

      .Filterable()
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable()
      .Groupable()
      )
```

as it was in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3egh1pFjZ88

but I get result with no entries.

**Update**

While debuging I got this JavaScript errors:

```
11:57:12.6249: Referenced file 'jquery.validate.js' not found.
11:57:12.6249: Referenced file 'jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js' not found.
11:57:12.6249: Referenced file 'knockout-2.2.0.debug.js' not found.
```

I added the missing files to script folder but I still get this error

and I have noticed that I'm not entering the "Get" method.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you debug the code? Does the controller get hit? Are you getting javascript errors in the console? Without knowing a bit more then it is difficult to say what the error could be as everything looks ok.

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler to see if the action gets called? eg do you get a 404. Also what scripts have you included on the layout for the page. Maybe you are missing one.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller I think you need to Explicitly tell it, is a Get so you need to add above the method name [GET], since the Controller action isn't actually called Get() it doesn't know you are trying to perform a get.